# Spring MVC: best way to set global debug flag

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC and my jsp's have a

```
<div id="debug">
```

section that I would like to be able to show/turn off conditionally while we are in development.  For example, if I am looking at page www.example.com/main, www.example.com/main?debug=1 would show me the information that is contained under the debug div.

Is there an easy way to do this?  Can I use a URL parameter, should I use a cookie?  I would appreciate any ideas you have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set it as context parameter in `web.xml`.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>debug</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And access it in EL by `${initParam}` which basically refers to a `Map<String, String>` with all context parameters. Here's an example with JSTL `c:if`:

```
<c:if test="${initParam.debug}">
    <div>Debug mode!</div>
</c:if>
```

There may be more "Springy" solutions for this which I am not aware of. But it's not that hard with help of standard JSP/Servlet API's :)